# Programatically download file from google cloud storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, boto, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to figure out how to download a file from google cloud storage bucket.

My use-case is to run a scheduled script which downloads a .csv file once a day and save it to a SQL DB.

I considered doing it using python and the google SDK but got lost with all the options and which one is the right for me.

Could someone can explain the difference between cloud storage client, boto, gsutil, and google cloud SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. You need to narrow it down to a smaller scope and show some effort to research or answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Look into gcs-fuse: Makes like a lot easier since you then can use the GCS as just a standard file system.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud SDK includes a `gsutil` program. It is based on the `boto` Python library.  "Cloud storage client" is not a specific thing as far as I'm aware.

If you have some kind of scheduler like `cron` that can regularly run a command, all you need is

```
gsutil cp gs://mybucket/somefile.csv /tmp/
```

How to load that into a SQL DB is a separate problem.